# Dereferencing char pointer causes segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am using `strchr` to find a point in the buffer where an `=` is encountered. Then I am changing that equal too character to a `M`. I get a segfault at the line where I try to do this.

This is the **FULL** code:

```
int main(void){
    char *buffer = "Name=Tom"
    char *pointer;
    pointer = strchr(buffer,'=');
    *pointer = 'M';    <--------- Segfault Occurs here
return (0);
}
```

I get the following error with the segfault:

```
Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
 Bad permissions for mapperd region at addresss .....
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You haven't even provided the definition and contents of `buffer` which is crucial to the question. For example, if `buffer` contains a string constant or does not contain any `=` characters then you would get a seg fault. But impossible to say with incomplete code like you have provided.

Comment: Maybe the character '=' isn't found, and strchr returns NULL

Comment: Since this question seems to be designed as a guessing game, I'd suspect that you've declare buffer like so:  `char *buffer="a buffer=something`, making it a constant literal value and read only.

Comment: @JohnDoe Now that you have finally added the code it is clear (as guessed by multiple people) that you are attempting to change a string literal. String literals are not writeable. Modify the `buffer` declaration to make it a char array instead: `char buffer[] = "Name=Tom";`

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I added the full code.

Comment: See [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string initialized with “char *s” but not “char s\[\]”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/164194/176646)

Answer (score 7):

You are not checking the return value of `strchr`, it could be `NULL` since we don't see your input.

In addition to this, where and how is `buffer` declared? not all `char*` can be modified, since they could be stored in data segment of the binary (as a string literal).

Comment: It is not NULL. I have added the error valgrind displays when the segfault happens.

Comment: Then the cause is the second I pointed out. That literal is read only and it is stored in data segment, try with char[] buffer = "..".

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting to modify the value of a string literal which will be stored in a read only memory segment.  This results in an access violation.

The problem is here:

```
char *buffer = "Name=Tom";
```

Modify it to be:

```
char buffer[] = "Name=Tom";
```

Comment: The problem with this method, is that since you are not specifying the size of buffer, it is automatically set to the length of "Name=Tom" plus one for '\0'. So if you want to place a string which is longer than the current one, it will give an error. Refer to this old post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803387/why-can-a-string-be-assigned-to-a-char-pointer-but-not-to-a-char-array

Comment: @RatanSenapathy I think you're completely missing the point.  I'm fully aware of how to allocate memory...  The OP was unaware of where that memory was being allocated and why he couldn't write to it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here is wrong:

```
char *buffer = "Name=Tom";
```

When you assign a string literal to a pointer it is stored as a `const char*`, which cannot be modified, which is what you are trying to do later in your code.

Here, you first need to allocate memory to `buffer` and then use `strcpy` to copy the contents like:

```
char buffer[100];
strcpy(buffer, "Name=Tom");
```

Comment: This is incorrect, Ahmed.  Try compiling it and try it out.  It's silently creating a `const char *`.

Comment: Or just `char buffer[] = "Name=Tom";` as [David Hoelzer showed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35280848/176646).